# Strings e Arrays, problemas a conseguir o resultado certo

Tags: c, array, string

O objetivo do programa é mostrar informações em uma opção e um inquerito de 10 perguntas em outra opção. Cada disciplina tem 10 perguntas, e cada disciplina esta feito em um subprograma. o problema é o uso da string.

```
typedef struct
{
    char pergunta[150];
    char resposta; // a, b, c
} Perguntas;
```

por exemplo

```
void discasc(void){
    int valasc,i;
    char resposta;
    char respostas[10];
    int certas = 0;
    Perguntas pITEL [10];
    strcpy(pITEL[0].pergunta,"...?\na. ...\nb. ...\nc. ...");
    pITEL[0].resposta = 'a';
```

mais dez perguntas diferentes, e para saber as certas ou erradas utiliza-se o seguinte

```
printf("Menu de ASC\n\n");
    printf("1 - Informação sobre a Disciplina;\n");
    printf("2 - Teste com perguntas aleatórias;\n");
    printf("3 - Voltar ao menu anterior.\n");
    scanf("%d",&valasc);
    if (valasc<1 || valasc>3)
        printf("O valor inserido não corresponde a nenhuma das opções anteriores.");
    switch(valasc) {
    case 1:
    printf("...");
    case 2:
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            resposta=0;
            printf("%s\n",pASC[i].pergunta);
            printf("A sua resposta: ");
            scanf("%c", &resposta);
            respostas[i]=resposta;
        }
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(pASC[i].resposta=respostas[i]){
                certas++;
            } else {
            printf("A resposta à pergunta %d está errada. A resposta certa é %c", pASC[i].resposta);
            }
            }
            printf("Resultado: %d \10", certas);
        }
        return;
        }
```

Comment: cuidado que tem um `=` dentro do `if`. Isso sempre vai dar verdadeiro, e vai mudar o valor do que está do lado esquerdo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas o problema ja está resolvido. Agradeço na mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José, trabalhar com strings e char em c é muito chato, mas com alguns artifícios você vai se acostumando.

Apesar de você não ter explicado muito bem, o que imagino que deve estar acontecendo é que está "pulando" alguns `scanf()`, isso acontece porque sempre que você utiliza um `scanf()` para ler um inteiro o seu buffer recebe um '\n', então seu programa fica esperando onde inserir esse '\n', ai quando chega no seu `scanf()` para ler o que será inserido nessa variável string/char o '\n' é inserido nela.

O que eu faço para evitar isso é sempre que vou ler uma variável inteira, em vez de colocar `scanf("%d", &varInt)`, eu coloco `scanf("%d%*c", &varInt)`, isso meio que esvazia seu buffer, não ocorrendo esse erro.

Tem algumas outras formas também, se você pesquisar aqui no StackOverflow você vai achar várias soluções. [Aqui](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2012/12/Buffer--o-que-e-como-limpar-e-as-funcoes-fflush-e-fpurge.html) também tem uma ótima explicação e várias soluções.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Você não especificou qual o seu problema!

Eu ia comentar mas como ainda não tenho permissão necessária, existe alguns erros no seu código:

```
// Aqui são dois sinais de iguais para comparar as respostas.
if(pASC[i].resposta == respostas[i])
{
    certas++;
} 
else 
{
    // Aqui você indicou que passará um inteiro "%d" para o printf mas não passou.
    printf("A resposta à pergunta %d está errada. A resposta certa é %c", i, pASC[i].resposta);
}
```

Comment: ok obrigado, e dificil dizer qual é o problema, mas essencialmente é quando corro o programa, ele faz as perguntas mas repete, ou seja, faz a pergunta (a) eu respondo e depois copia a pergunta (a), faz a pergunta (b) mas nao me deixa responder e ainda faz a pergunta (c) e me deixa responder. so com o código fonte é que me poderia ajudar mas facilmente.